# SQL Server: reasonable "auto increment" techniques?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I'm using SQL Server 2005 for the first time, having mostly worked with MySQL in the past.  I'm used to using auto_increment to create unique IDs in tables.

Anyway... I'm working in a java app, and need to do the following.  Presume my table has two columns: itemID (int) and itemValue(int).

This is basically what I want to do (the dbconn methods are just pseudocode):

```
dbconn.execSQL("begin tran");
int nextID = dbconn.execSQLSelect("select max(itemID)+1 from itemTable");
dbconn.execSQLInsert("insert into itemTable values " + nextID + ", 1000");
dbconn.execSQL("commit tran");
```

Will the begin/commit tran statements deal with the possible race condition between lines 2 and 3?  Or is there some TSQL equivalent of MySQL's "lock table" that I need to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just make the column itemID [IDENTITY ON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196(SQL.80).aspx) and let MS SQL engine handle it. Handling identity incrementation on your own is very very unstable.

Comment: And use the OUtput clause to return the identity  if you need to or use scope_Identity(), do not use @@identity.

Comment: Is there some kind of "lock table" alternative that I could use here to make the auto-incrementing behavior more stable?  For various reasons that would take too long to go into, I need to have explicit control over the unique IDs themselves.

Answer (score 2):

You should make an [`IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775%28SQL.90%29.aspx) column.